# Issue with Selenium, I don't know which locator I should use

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am coding a script in java to automate a test case in Selenium.
Unfortunatelly I am totally blocked in one step.

I am unable to use a locator to click an element.

This is what I see about the element in my Browser´s Development Tool (I would like to upload a photo but I need more reputation to do it :( )

```
<li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="site_~_listUtilities|site" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable file" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"></span><img src="http://mucs70064.corp.knorr-bremse.com:1080/Windchill/netmarkets/images/sp.gif" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-end"><img src="http://mucs70064.corp.knorr-bremse.com:1080/Windchill/netmarkets/images/default_leaf.png" class="x-tree-node-icon x-tree-node-inline-icon" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="http://mucs70064.corp.knorr-bremse.com:1080/Windchill/app/#ptc1/site/listUtilities?oid=OR%3Awt.inf.container.ExchangeContainer%3A5&amp;u8=1" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Dienstprogramme</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li>
```

Can you please how can I proceed?

Thanks in advance
Pablo

Comment: Pablo, you can upload an image at [imgur](http://imgur.com/) and share the link here

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to click on the anchor element:

```
WebElement myAnchor = yourDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.x-tree-node-anchor"));
myAnchor.click();
```

where `yourDriver` is your instance of `WebDriver`

**Note:** This might find multiple links if your are doing it straight from the `yourDriver` since that will check the entire page, so unless there is only one anchor tag with that class name on the page I'd suggest reducing the scope of the search by executing another `findElement` beforehand so you find the exact `li` node you want to click on (the one detailed in your post).

Then for example if you saved that `li` node `WebElement` under the name `myClickableListItem` you can then call the code mentioned at the start of this post by replacing `yourDriver` with `myClickableListItem`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 2 options here.  I assume that you are wanting to click the link.

#### Option 1

The *href* could be unique enough to be identifiable, assuming that is the only link on the page that navigates to that page.  If so,

```
// this will find any link on the page with an href that contains site/listUtilities
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='site/listUtilities']").click();
```

#### Option 2

If the *href* isn't unique enough, use the pseudo-id that the `<div>` has attached.

```
// this will find a div with an attribute `ext:tree-node-id` that contains site, and listUtilities, then trickle down to the `a` that is within it.
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[ext\\:tree-node-id*='site'][ext\\:tree-node-id*='listUtilities'] a")).click();
```

I think these are your safest, and most specific options.